# Threading a paint method

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, paintcomponent, event-dispatch-thread

I was wondering how I would thread the following code, or just a method in general:

```
public void run (){

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.fillRect(20, 20, 20, 20);
        for (int i = 20; i < 1000; i++) {
            g.fillRect(20, i, 20, 20);
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
    }
}
```

I find that I am unable to make a thread of this code because I get an illegal start of expression error, which is fair but I do not see a way around it.

Comment: You are not allowed to do painting outside of the Gui thread. You can't redirect drawing to a secondary thread.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Its hard to tell what you are doing,

but seems like you are trying to override `paint()` of a `Runnable` from within its `run()` method.

This can surely not be done.

The logic is

- Take a component
- Override its paint method to draw what we need
- Call method to update co-ordinates of rectangle (or in this case timer will do that)
- Than call `repaint()` on the component so paint method may be called again and redraw the rectangle with its new co-ordinates (Timer would also take care of repainting after changing co-ordinates of Rectangle)
- repeat last 2 steps as many times as needed/wanted

(when I say *component* I actually mean `JPanel`, *paint method* refers to overridden `paintComponent(..)` of `JPanel` as this is best practice.)

**Some suggestions:**

1) Dont override `paint` rather use `JPanel` and override `paintComponent`.

2) Dont forget to honor the *paint chain* and call `super.XXX` implementation of overridden `paintComponent(Graphics g)` (or any overridden method for that fact) unless purposefully leaving it out. i.e

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

         //do drawings here
    }
}
```

3) If drawing in `paintComponent` it is usually needed to override `getPreferredSize()` and return `Dimension`s which fit the contents/drawings of `JPanel`, i.e:

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
         return new Dimension(300,300);
    }
}
```

3) Look at [`Swing Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead of `Thread.sleep(..)` as `sleep` will block GUI thread and make it seem to be frozen. i.e

```
Timer t = new Timer(10, new AbstractAction() {
    int count = 20;
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if (count < 1000) {
            //increment rectangles y position
            //now repaint container so we can see changes in co-ordinates (unless you have a timer which repaints for you too)
            count++;
        } else {//counter is at 1000 stop the timer
            ((Timer) ae.getSource()).stop();
        }
    }
});
t.start();
```

4) An alternative (because I see for now you are only moving a `Rectangle` which is not a Swing component) to Swing timer is [`TimerTask`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html), and this can be used as long as no Swing components will be created/manipulated from within its `run()` method (as `TimerTask` does not run on EDT like Swing Timer). Note `revalidate()` and `repaint()` are *Thread-safe* so it can be used within `TimerTask`.

The advantage of the above is unnecessary code is kept of EDT (i.e moving AWT rectangle by changing co-ords) i.e

```
    final TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (count < 1000) {
               //increment rectangles y position
                //now repaint container so we can see changes in co-ordinates (unless you have a timer which repaints for you too)
            count++;
            } else {//counter is at 1000 stop the timer
                cancel();
            }
        }
    };

    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(tt, 0, 10);//start in 0milis and call run every 10 milis
```

Comment: @NickHaughton Also see this similar answer which uses a single Swing Timer, to move a ball and repaint its container afterwards to refelect changes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068472/java-mouselistener-action-event-in-paintcomponent/14070147#14070147